# How can I Include extremely large outliers in analytics?

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, dataset, outliers

Like most of us stuck at home, I'm taking time to get back up to speed with machine learning with some pet projects and one of my projects includes trying to use machine learning to predict missing data.  I'm using corporate financial data as an example with a goal to predict depreciation for companies who do not report it.

My problem is, my results are really bad(order of magnitude off actuals), and I was talking to a friend who thought maybe because my data range was so large it maybe resulting in bad results. Here's the distribution of the data:

```
df['depreciation'].describe()
count    1.687800e+04
mean     7.816402e+09
std      2.124805e+11
min     -3.896300e+10
25%      4.308675e+07
50%      1.422000e+08
75%      4.810000e+08
max      1.632600e+13
Name: depreciation, dtype: float64
```

[image: Here's a hist of the data]

I think the problem is most companies who's data I have aren't that huge but firms like amazon and apple's huge numbers create large outliers. I am hesitant to delete them because large firms and small firms may add value to the prediction.

I read a few articles on this and most say either normalize(which I did use MinMaxScaler) or drop outliers which I'm hesitant to do.

**My questions What are my options for working with these large ranges of data?**

I'm totally new to this so if I'm missing any information please let me know and I'll get it asap.  Thank you!

Comment: you could log-scale your data.  You could pre-cluster it, and then perform analysis conditioned on the cluster membership.  There are options.  They are driven by your goal.  I think you are looking and power-law relationships, the place where gray swans and dragon kings live, so log-scale isn't a bad first step.  You might use the R stock analysis tools, and get company metadata as part of your clustering.  There might be other numbers that flag that data is missing or inform its estimation, or estimation error.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful and I'll research this. In terms of preclusting, would that take away from the transferring of knowledge between corporations? For example, perhaps apples financials has a similar relationship to a small startup who's data I a missing.

Comment: If you had some plausible "dummy data" then an answer could have description, code, and demo-outputs.